# optimizing performance while reducing use of template

Tags: c++, templates

In my application I've gained a speed-up of roughly 2x by introducing special cases for a structure.

Simplified, my code looks like this:

```
class SpecialCase
{
   private:
      size_t values[10];
   public:
      void foo();
};

class GenericCase
{
   private:
      std::vector<size_t> values;
   public:
      void foo();
};

template <class Case> void bar()
{
   Case case;
   case.foo();
}

void somewhereElse()
{
   if ( boring_runtime_condition )
   {
      bar<SpecialCase>();
   }
   else
   {
      bar<GenericCase>();
   }
}
```

There's no problem with this bit of the code, but now I have to extend the application by another class:

```
class Problem
{
   private:
      std::vector<Case> cases;
   public:
      Case doSomething();
};
```

To work with both SpecialCase and GenericCase I would have to make the whole class a template. Since I have several special cases, this drastically slows down compilation. I don't like that at all.

I never mix SpecialCase and GenericCase in a run of the application. I would very much like to not have to cast my Case to the specific type *in every method*, since it bloats the code and other developers might forget about it.

Is there a nice way to avoid this template madness? (C++11 solutions are welcome too)

Disclaimer: Please don't tell me about how great `std::vector` is and that I shouldn't use the special cases. I measured the performance, so please don't leave a comment that you don't believe a 2x speed-up. It's fact and this question is not about it.

Comment: Shouldn't the two branches of `if ( boring_runtime_condition )` be swapped?

Comment: @AndyProwl why would that matter? it's over-simplified near-pseudo code.

Comment: Nevermind. I was just trying to make sense out of it

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to create a lot of instances of `std::vector`, you could make a small proxy class that stores everything by reference and cast only in this class. If it is small, the instantiation won't be too slow.

```
template<class T>
class Problem {
    private:
        std::vector< some_smart_pointer > cases;
    public:
        T cast(Case* x) {
             return (T*)x;
        }
        T doSomething() {
             //doing something
              return cast(returnValue);
        }
};
```

I called the class `Problem`, but It is better to make some other layer `ProxyVector` that is used only as a proxy and use it in `Problem`